# How do I change a textfield in an AlertDialog box to a list of clickable items which in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, popupwindow, flutter-alertdialog, table-calendar

In my table calendar, the input from the textfield is currently displayed as shown. However, I want to change it to option [when I input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICTHa.png)
[after input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkKSy.png)

Here is my current code:

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('What is your mood today?'),
            content: TextField(
                controller: _eventController,
            ),
            actions: < Widget > [
                TextButton(
                    child: Text("Save"),
                    onPressed: () {
                        if (_eventController!.text.isEmpty) return;
                        setState(() {
                            if (_events![_controller?.selectedDay] != null) {
                                _events![_controller?.selectedDay] !.add(_eventController?.text);
                            } else {
                                _events![_controller!.selectedDay] = [_eventController?.text];
                            }
                            prefs?.setString("events", json.encode(encodeMap(_events!)));
                            _eventController?.clear();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                    },
                )
            ],
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) and instead of returning an `AlertDialog` return a `MultiSelectDialog`:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => MultiSelectDialog(
      items: _items,
      onConfirm: (values) {...},
  );
);
```

The package is well documented so you can learn to use it reasonably fast.